# remove spaces from string - regex

Tags: json, regex, type-conversion, apache-nifi

I have a csv file with string fields containing digits separated by whitespaces (thousand's separator), example "1 025 000" instead of "1025000".

I want to remove those whitespaces, only for the fields with digits so i could do a conversion to double with jolt transform to get a json file on output, i'm doing this on apache nifi with replaceText processor using regex expression.

this is an example of my csv :

```
Client1;Client2;Client3;price1;price2;price3
john smith;john2 smith2;john3 smith3;1 145;125;129 009
```

This expression that i'm using doesn't do the job : `(\s?=(\d{3},?)+(?:\.\d{1,3})?")`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure there is a single regex which would be fool-proof here.  My first instinct says that you should go back to the source of your JSON and change the formatting of the numbers.  Is there some reason why you cannot do this?

Comment: in apache-nifi i receive text that i convert to json, i can't do the conversion before the json step

Comment: You don't want to use regex on JSON *at all*, period. Parse the JSON, transform the contained data (you may use regex for that), serialize the data back to JSON. Every other approach is wrong. (Unless you are already doing that, then please include the jolt transformation you have so far.)

Comment: I didn't explain it well, i have a csv file in input that i want to apply the regex on to remove the spaces between numbers with replacetext of nifi. the jolt is for the conversion to double and it is applied on the json that i get on output

Comment: Could you show a part of your CSV file? It's hard to match only numbers when we have no idea what the other entries look like.

Comment: Without an example is really dificult to try help you.

Comment: I added an example of my csv file

Answer (score 4):

Although you can do that via NiFi, I would suggest you to try changing the source and possibly correct the way the numbers are formatted and written.

Anyway, one way that comes immediately to my mind is to make use of `ExecuteScript` processor to handle the whitespace part.

Assume you have the CSV as this:

```
name,val
item1, 1 345 000
item2, 2 432
```

You can use the `SplitRecord` processor to convert the CSV to JSON and split it by 1 record. Feed the output of this to `ExecuteScript`.

You can have the following `Groovy` code to read the flowfile content and replace all the whitespaces

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile)return

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def text = ''

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
    input = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    inputJson = jsonSlurper.parseText(input)
    inputJson.val = inputJson.val.replaceAll("\\s", "")
    outputStream.write(inputJson.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Connect the `success` relationship of `ExecuteScript` to a processor as demanded by your usecase. Anyway, the output for the provided input will look like this:

```
{
  "name" : "item1",
  "val" : "1345000"
}

{
  "name" : "item2",
  "val" : "2432"
}
```

Comment: Sivaprasanna's suggestion is good. I would go a step further and offer using [`ConvertRecord`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertRecord/index.html) with a `CSVReader` and a [`ScriptedRecordSetWriter`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.record.script.ScriptedRecordSetWriter/index.html) which would allow you to write the re-formatted values out in CSV or JSON inline, so you don't need to split and generate extra flowfiles.

Comment: your suggestion is good but i have also fields that i don't want to remove the whitespaces from. is there a way to adapt the regex expression just for the numbers?

Comment: If you look at the Groovy code posted above, it is only removing the whitespaces from `val` field, not from all the fields. If you are working with very few fields, you can use this approach.